# Allow third party developer to call Docusign API without using admin credentials

Tags: docusignapi

We have employed a third party developer to create a small web site that creates embedded envelopes on our behalf to be signed by users. They are currently using their own sandbox account with API id.

We would prefer for them to not have to use our login credentials to make the rest calls when we move to production. Is there a way to create an application service account with the permissions to call the API with our integrator id that would allow them to make the calls on our behalf and only store the service account credentials instead of our admin credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Admin account is not required to send an envelopes, you can create a DS Sender user in your account to send envelopes from your DS Account. Also, system is not required to save the DS Sender user's login credentials in the database, instead they should use [Service Integration Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) to generate the `AccessToken` of the sender user, and call DS APIs with the help of `AccessToken`.